# Send camera video via 3.5mm TV output to video transmitter (5.8GHz)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, picamera

I have got a Raspberry pi 3 b+, a simple camera connected to it, and a pair of video transmitter and receiver. What I want to do is to send the video signal (the video recorded by the camera) to the 3.5mm jack (raspberry tv output TRRS, composite output), where the video transmitter is connected. Then the transmitter would send the signal to the receiver and I would see the recorded video on a screen connected to the receiver.

Actually, the raspberry computer will be on a copter, and will be connected to pixhawk.

So, how can I do it in Python 3? Receive the camera video and send it to the 5.8GHz receiver via a video transmitter, which is connected to raspberry on 3.5mm jack?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad for this site. We don't design whole systems for people. If you give it a try and run into specific problems, people are happy to help with those as they arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one not very good solution, which is suitable to my problem for now.

I managed to output the whole video signal (not only the camera video) via 3.5mm TV output. Then I ran a script to make the camera video full screen, and got the camera video on the receiver screen.